# Utilizing GPU memory for cloned workers in Keras

Tags: keras, tensorflow

Is it possible to make Keras exploit as much as possible from each single GPU?

For example, with 2 GPUs of 10GB each and a 1-GB memory model I would expect a 20x increase training time by dividing the training set and cloning the model 10 times on each GPU.

Instead, I only found the `multi_gpu_model` option ( https://keras.io/utils/#multi_gpu_model ), which replicates the model on *several* GPUs. This helps in only 2x better performance, since it replicates the model once on each GPU.

Using `fit_generator` options such as `use_multiprocessing=True` does not help in this manner.

Is such a replication/performance increase possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Not the best answer, I know... but you might try to manually create threads, each thread having its own model (copies of the main model), split your data equally between these threads (define start and end points in the generator, for instance), and start an independent `fit` for each thread.

Comment: Why not increase the batch size? The reason the option doesn't exist is because increasing the batch size is the way to address the problem.

Comment: Different batch sizes may yield different results, and it is sometimes beneficial to use small batch sizes. Also, it makes it harder to compare with other models that use a specific batch size. I'm not sure if that is the reason this was not implemented, I thought that for the most part, models occupy most of the GPU anyway, whereas I have a small model.

Comment: Memory is not the only resource on GPU. Actual computation can also be a limiting factor. If you are running a model on a GPU, even if on a small batch size, it will still be using a good chunk of available computation resources. Having said that, one can imagine a clever way of batching steps from separate model instances into one actual GPU operation, but you are not likely to get 10x from this. My guess is that this use case was never very important to warrant such a design.